# Installed wrong SharePoint CU

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Someone installs a SharePoint Enterprise CU on a SharePoint Foundation environment.  It was not realized until after the config wizard was run.
Now, when I try to run the SP Foundation CU, is says there are no products affected by this package installed on this system.

Any suggestions on how to get my environment back to SharePoint Foundation?

Comment: if want to force run CU again can use "your package file" PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/malvarez/2015/09/22/message-the-expected-version-of-the-product-was-not-found-on-the-system-when-install-cummulative-updates-in-project-server/

Answer (score 2):

You're good to go. The Server CU includes the Foundation CU and will not apply any components that do not need to be updated (or don't exist!).

Comment: But my servers all say "Upgrade Available".  when I try to run the correct CU, I get a message saying:  There are no products affected by this package installed on this system.  I'm concerned about the databases.  You don't think they were updated?  I'm concerned that features may have been added.  How can I check this?

Comment: Did you run the config wizard on all of your SharePoint servers?

Comment: Config wizard was ran on all servers.